# How to use line breaks in PowerShell Method-Chaining

Tags: powershell, syntax, syntax-error, fluent

I am trying to use a Retry Service that is written in the fluent-api pattern.
The methods return the service and allow a chaining of methods.
However even though i am using --> **`** <-- i see a lot of errors as shown below.
[image]

Is there any workaround or other possibility to not write everything into one line?
(I already checked the methods names and return types)

(Entry point of RetryService)
[image]

Comment: the dot has to be at the end of each statement then you can continue with the method on a new line without problem (no need for the backticks). the parser will not allow you to do it other way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately [**about_Methods**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods?view=powershell-7.3) doesn't seem to have a clarification on method chaining and its parsing rules. If you want to chain multiple methods on new lines, the dot `.` has to be at the end of each statement then a newline is allowed. The **backticks are not needed**.

In example:

```
[powershell]::Create().
    AddScript({ "hello $args" }).
    AddArgument('world').
    Invoke()
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to chain method calls is to use the `ForEach-Object` command (alias `%`). This relies on the parameter set with the [`-MemberName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3#-membername) parameter (implicitly by passing a string as the 1st argument).

**PowerShell 7+** even lets you write the pipe symbol `|` on a new line:

```sh
[powershell]::Create()
    |% AddScript { "hello $args" }
    |% AddArgument 'world'
    |% Invoke
```

If there are multiple method arguments, you have to separate them by `,` (parentheses are unnecessary).

For **PS 5 and below** you have to use a slightly different syntax because the pipe symbol has to be on the same line as the previous command:

```sh
[powershell]::Create() |
    % AddScript { "hello $args" } |
    % AddArgument 'world' |
    % Invoke
```

Is this a better way than using member access operator `.`? I don't think so, it's just a different way. IMO it does look more consistent compared to regular PowerShell commands. Performance might be even worse than `.` but for high level code it propably doesn't matter (I haven't measured).

Comment: Nice; indeed, a pipeline-based solution with `%` (`ForEach-Object`) is slower (which may often not matter, as you state).